# Counting knockout validation error messages in a public function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a `jsFiddle` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asad23/tRVCr/):

There is an array in knockout viewmodel and every array element raises an error. Is there a way to count number of error messages for the whole view model and access it by a public javascript function?

The idea here is to count total errors of the viewmodel and then perform some action outside in a javascript public function.

Thanks

Comment: What is a public JavaScript function?  Are you asking if you can access the view model objects outside of the view model or outside of window?

Comment: Yes. Explanation, I am using a web form and a custom validator on it. Now the custom validator client side function will determine if the view model is valid or not before postback. This client side function will be a simple public javascript function which needs to access if error length of the whole viewmodel is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/js8hh/4/

```
        self.Errors = ko.computed(function() {
            var errs = [];
            for(var p in self) {
                if(self.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    var pObj = self[p];
                    if(!!!ko.validation.utils.isValidatable(self[p])) {
                        console.info("ope, nvm");
                    } else {                            
                        if(!ko.validation.validateObservable(pObj)) {
                            errs.push({'Property':p,'Error':ko.utils.unwrapObservable(pObj.error)});
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    console.trace("skipping prototype property");
                }
            }
            return errs;
        });
```

and then at the bottom

```
            addJointHolder: addJointHolder,
            AllErrors: ko.computed(function() {
                result = []
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(jointholders(),function(jh) {
                    if(jh.Errors().length > 0) {
                        result.push({'JointHolder':jh,'Errors':jh.Errors()});
                    }
                });
                return result;
            })
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks @scaryman, just made you ahead of me in Stackoverflow's points row :)

Comment: There is a built in way of doing this, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why not use built in functionality instead?

```
ko.validation.group
```

It returns a observable array with the errors

http://jsfiddle.net/tRVCr/4/

Comment: Can you please help to count the errors in my fiddle through this builtin function? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Anders, but your solution is only calculating errors of first row. If jointholders are added on the page, the errors don't get accumulated.

Comment: Ah, its a old bug in the library (It does not listen to array changes), I thought that was fixed, you can fix it like this http://jsfiddle.net/tRVCr/5/

Comment: Thanks @Andres, better possible solution. Apart from remove functionality been broken it works well too.